# how to get a variable in the link_to path

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to use a variable in the following link_to call:

```
<%= link_to '<button type = "button">Players</button>'
    .html_safe, live_players_path(:Team => @tmf) %>
```

but every time i click this it no longer has the value of the variable which was set here:

```
<select id = "FilterTm">
    <option>Select a Team...</option>
<% Abbrv.order("Team").each do |abbrv| %>
    <option><%= abbrv.Team %></option>
<% end %>
</select>
```

using an ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#FilterTm').change(function(){
        Tm = $('#FilterTm').val();
        SelectTm = true;
        $.ajax (
            {
                url: "http://localhost:3000/live_players.json' +
                    '?TmFilter="+Tm+"&Selected="+SelectTm,
                type: "get",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Loading Players....");
                },
                error: function(error) 
                {
                    alert("Failed " + console.log(error) + " " + error);
                }
            });
    });
});
```

So in summary, I select a Team from the select dropdown, which triggers the ajax, which set the @tmf variable in the controller, but when clicking the link_to, the variable (@tmf) is nil. How can i get the variable to stay so it can be used later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets rendered on the server & sent to the client during the first request from the user:

```
<%= link_to '<button type = "button">Players</button>'
    .html_safe, live_players_path(:Team => @tmf) %>
```

The ajax request is a separate request.  Changing @tmf on the server during the ajax request only changes @tmf on the server.  It has to be sent to the client.  You will have to make the server side of the ajax request send the new @tmf value to the client, then write custom javascript to set the value of the href.  Something like this:

No need to use rails here...

```
<a id="playerBtn"><button type="button">Players</button></a>
```

THe javascript pseudocode:

```
var playerBtn = $("#playerBtn");    

...

success: function(data) {
  alert("Loading Players....");
  playerBtn.href= "url/?Team=" + data.tmf;
},
```

Comment: ok let me try to see if i understand this. Instead of a link_to, i use a button, and when the button is clicked it will trigger my ajax using the url `url: "http://localhost:3000/live_players.json' +
                    '?TmFilter="+Tm+"&Selected="+SelectTm,` Then upon success, set the button's href to the appropriate link to get my view to refresh the table?

Comment: Awesome, once i understood what to do, then i turned your suggestion to regular code and voilà! Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Btw for others that see this post I really just used:

`$('selector').attr('href', 'url');`

selector being the element, and the url being the requested information.